# OAuth PHP cURL GET Request

Tags: php, curl, twitter, oauth

I'm making an OAuth library and am running across an issue with the Twitter implementation. While what I have already works for Flickr, and is returning the right access tokens and keys, when I make the request to the Twitter API for information, I receive the ambiguous Code 32: "Could not authenticate you".

Could anyone have a look at the code below and point out where it's going wrong? As said earlier, I believe it must be this step as the other steps are the same with flickr and are working fine, but this step is dealt with differently:

```
$oauth = array('oauth_consumer_key' => 'key',
      'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
      'oauth_timestamp' => 1415633132,
      'oauth_nonce' => 1817099296,
      'oauth_version' => '1.0', 
      'oauth_token' => 'token',
      'oauth_signature' => 'signature'
      );

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth){
$r = 'Authorization: OAuth '; 

$values = array(); //temporary key=value array
foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
    $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; 

$r .= implode(',', $values);
return $r; 

}

function sendRequest($oauth){
$header = array( buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:'); 

$options = array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header, 
                       CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                       CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=london',
                       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false); 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}
```

Comment: `'oauth_token' => token',` missing quote

Comment: That's just a typo in removing the secure parameter - the actual key etc is passed dynamically to there. I simplified the process of how the secure parameters are shown for clarity's sake.